# Google Visualization API fails in IE8, 9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, google-visualization

I am building a website that uses Google Visualization API, and it works fine (even in IE), except for production server. Basically:

- In all browsers not made by microsoft it works;
- In IE8, 9 on the dev server (localhost:8000) it works;
- In production, it fails saying 'Your browser does not support charts', which is not true.

No https involved, js is taken from Google, no browser or js errors at all. HTML from dev and production server is the same, I actually checked with the diff tool.

Any ideas on why can this happen or how do I fix this? Example URL: http://publishedin.com/websites/profile/penpen.in/ (graphs are in the left column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar charts running in IE 9 without a problem. Other people have noticed this problem when there is some kind of code collusion on the page.

So, try creating a page that only runs the charts, nothing else. If it works, there is some code on the page interfering with the chart creation.

I got your charts to run in IE 8 & 9:

http://www.jensbits.com/demos/charts.php

I have found IE to be particularly intolerant of code that confuses it.